# Send data inside an html type='button'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div with an attention message. Clients can close this div with a child (input type='button') placed in the far right corner.

My goal is to close the message for 30 minutes after which it will re-appear. To do this i need to send the current time to ajax which in turn posts it to a session['field'].

I'm really not sure what the correct way to send data is, from inside a button.

I found the following works.. but i'm just making up random attributes which can't be good?

PHP

```
<input type="button" class="close" crazyfieldnametime="<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Jquery

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("crazyfieldnametime"));
});
```

Is there a best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTML5 **data-*** attributes, The data attribute name must be at least one character long and must be prefixed with 'data-'. It should not contain any uppercase letters.

PHP

```
<input type="button" class="close" data-crazyfieldnametime="<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Jquery

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("crazyfieldname"));
});
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll get you that big green tick when the system allows!

Comment: @user2950370, Also go through http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom data attribute as that is allowed by html

e.g.

```
<input type="button" class="close" data-time="<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

and then

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("time"));
});
```